# Copy file in Java without locking the original

Tags: java, copy, locking

I have a folder containing 20 files, "myFile1.txt" to "myFile20.txt". A program, lets call it "WRITER", might write to these files.

Now, I'd like to copy the folder in Java using [FileUtils by Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), more specifically the method [FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectoryToDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)). However, I'm afraid that if I use the method, I will lock the files during the copy process such that the "WRITER" program cannot write to the files anymore.

Does anyone know if the method in FileUtils locks the files? How can I prevent locking the original files when copying (if that is even the case)?

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I'm using Windows

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that all the Linux based locks are advisory in nature. The caller has to check the lock. In that sense, it is not a foolproof solution. Since renaming of a file in the same directory is an atomic operation, the best approach may be to rename the file to some random name, copy to the new directory and delete the old file.

If you have control over both readers and writers of the file, you can use nio.FileChannel and lock functionality provided by it. Both reader and writers have to check the lock before accessing.

Comment: I updated my question by mentioning that I'm using Windows. Can you clarify what you mean by renaming the file? I will look into the nio.FileChannel class, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a bunch of Paradox DB files that I need to copy without locking them. I tested today this method from https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-file.
I used a buffer of 256 * 1024 as from my tests produced the best speed.
The file I used for testing had aprox 240 MB

```
public void givenIoAPI_whenCopied_thenCopyExistsWithSameContents(String original, String copied) 
  throws IOException {
    File original = new File(original);
    File copied = new File(copied);
    
    try (
      InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(original));
      OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(copied))) {
 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[262144];
        int lengthRead;
        while ((lengthRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, lengthRead);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
 
}
```